# JavaScript debugging not working in visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9, visual-studio-debugging

Hi there i have downgraded internet explorer  from ie 10 to ie 9. As a result of this the javascript debugger is not working in visual studio 2010 i have installed 64 bit version of the ie9. how  can i make it work?

i have also tried : 
Disable script debugging in Internet Explorer. but that didnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try "debugger;" anywhere in between javascript codes.It Works as a breakpoint . I'm not sure it works in IE but it surely works in Chrome.   :)